# How to make Eclipse treat Maven merged uberwar as a Web Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-cargo, m2e-wtp

I have a relative big Maven build. And it produced a merged war file through the maven-cargo-plugin.

However, when I tried to provide a Debug environment for devs, this Maven project is not treated as Web Project in Eclipse.

How to make eclipse treat a `<packaging>uberwar</packaging>` as Web Project.

I found an [according answer for Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207605).  Could anyone help me out for eclipse?

Comment: I have a temporary solution for this problem: define a seperate maven webapp and declare dependency on the <packaging>uberwar</packaging> maven project. However, this gave me two copies of same .war. Looking forward to a better solution.